# Timestamp to milisecond conversion

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner to mysql.

I would like to convert a timestamp like this "12:00:00 AM.260" to miliseconds.

The reference for the conversion will be "12:00:00 AM.000".

How should i go about this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function.

From the example

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
        -> 128885
```

You could use the microsecond unit and divide by 1000 - MySQL doesn't appear
to support milliseconds. HTH.

[EDIT in response to OP]

Take a  look at the code below - notice the 1 millisecond difference in the two
returned values. I tested for up to 50 years and it works fine on my 64 bit fedora linux system.

It is even accurate to 1 microsecond in 50 years - but you can use [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) to 
get suitable values.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, '2014-12-10 13:00:00.000', '2014-12-11 13:56:00.000')/1000 AS Milliseconds_Elapsed FROM Dual;
+----------------------+
| Milliseconds_Elapsed |
+----------------------+
|        89760000.0000 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, '2014-12-10 13:00:00.000', '2014-12-11 13:56:00.001')/1000 AS Milliseconds_Elapsed FROM Dual;
+----------------------+
| Milliseconds_Elapsed |
+----------------------+
|        89760001.0000 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

50 years (+ 1 microsecond)

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, '2014-12-10 13:00:00.000', '2062-12-11 13:56:00.001')/1000 AS Milliseconds_Elapsed FROM Dual;
+----------------------+
| Milliseconds_Elapsed |
+----------------------+
|   1514854560001.0000 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, '2014-12-10 13:00:00.000', '2062-12-11 13:56:00.000001')/1000 AS Milliseconds_Elapsed FROM Dual;
+----------------------+
| Milliseconds_Elapsed |
+----------------------+
|   1514854560000.0010 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I have come up with a partial solution (maybe someone wiser could help me simplify this) :

```
select microsecond (TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.010','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'),STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'))) /1000;
select second (TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'),STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'))) *1000;
select minute (TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'),STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'))) *60*1000;
select hour (TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'),STR_TO_DATE ('12:00:00 AM.000','%h:%i:%S %p.%f'))) *60*60*1000;
```

Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Thank you !